# why does it says it is a string?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am very very new in android app development and I need to get data from my local xampp mysql database. These are the error message I keep getting.

```
06-15 15:12:31.472  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
06-15 15:12:31.472  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
06-15 15:12:31.472  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
06-15 15:12:31.472  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
06-15 15:12:31.472  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem.StudentJSONParser.parseFeed(StudentJSONParser.java:18)
06-15 15:12:31.472  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem.MainActivity$ThreadClass.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:111)
06-15 15:12:31.472  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem.MainActivity$ThreadClass.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:95)
06-15 15:12:31.472  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
06-15 15:12:31.472  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
06-15 15:12:31.472  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
06-15 15:12:31.473  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-15 15:12:31.473  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-15 15:12:31.473  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
06-15 15:12:31.473  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-15 15:12:31.473  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-15 15:12:31.473  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
06-15 15:12:31.473  28252-28252/com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is my php file get_all_products.php

```
<?php // array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $response[] = $row;
}
// success

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No students found";

// echo no users JSON
header(‘Content-type: application/json’);
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

The results of get_all_products.php if I run it on my browser and it seems right...

```
[{"student_id":"TP028616","student_name":"Shirlyn Hoe Yee Lyn","student_username":"lyn","student_password":"123"},{"student_id":"TP033500","student_name":"Ryan Teh Hoon Meng","student_username":"teh","student_password":"123"}]
```

This is my java class in my android app StudentJSONParser.java

```
package com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StudentJSONParser {
    public static List<Student> parseFeed(String content){

        try {
            System.out.println("begin parsing");
            JSONArray ar = new JSONArray(content);
            List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < ar.length() ; i++){
                System.out.println("loop " + i);
                JSONObject obj = ar.getJSONObject(i);
                Student student = new Student(obj.getString("student_id"), obj.getString("student_name"), obj.getString("student_username"), obj.getString("student_password"));

                studentList.add(student);
                System.out.println("complete loop " + i);
            }
            System.out.println("complete parsing");

            return studentList;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("error parsing");

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

so is this the problem with the .php file not returning jsonarrays? or the logic of my app is wrong? Thanks for all the replies in advance.

this is my asynctask class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button loginbtn;
private EditText usernameTxt, passwordTxt;
private ProgressBar pb;

private List<Student> studentslist;

public final static String readStudentphp = "http://192.168.0.103/webservice/get_all_products.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OnClickButtonListener();
    initLogin();
    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

private void initLogin(){
    usernameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameTxt);
    passwordTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordTxt);
}

private void OnClickButtonListener(){
    loginbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    loginbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void requestData(String uri){
    ThreadClass t = new ThreadClass();
    t.execute(uri);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    requestData(readStudentphp);
    //Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.shirlyn.attendancesystem.MainMenu");
    //startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class ThreadClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String content = HTTPManager.getData(params[0]);

        return content;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        System.out.println("Before parsing");
        studentslist = StudentJSONParser.parseFeed(result);
        System.out.println("After parsing");
        if(studentslist != null && studentslist.size() > 0)
            System.out.println(studentslist.get(0).getStudent_name());
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just going off your title I'd guess maybe you need to send the appropriate headers when you send the JSON.... 'application/json'  What is the exact error?

Comment: You are missing `header(‘Content-type: application/json’);` when there are results, I would suggest to use a simple response class that will take care of this.

Comment: it was an error, i removed it in my php file. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to parse HTML as JSON (based on the `<br` tag in your error).

`<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Double check the output you are trying to parse to make sure you are getting JSON back from your end point. Might be a accepts header or something like that.

Comment: so there is nothing wrong with my php file? from the json arrays, i wanted to save them in an array.

Comment: @user3244616 if the above answer solved your problem you can accept the answers. And what do you mean with there is nothing wrong with my php file?

Comment: It's not clear that you are hitting the PHP code you intend do. If you look at the entire string that you are trying to parse as JSON you should be able to figure out what is returning that HTML. The PHP code I see doesn't appear to return HTML, so it stands to reason you are not hitting it or are getting an error like @MarcB suggested.

Comment: there is **SOMETHING** wrong with your php file, and it's outputting html. usually that means you've got a PHP warning/error, which will contain html.

Comment: [{"student_id":"TP028616","student_name":"Shirlyn Hoe Yee Lyn","student_username":"lyn","student_password":"123"},{"student_id":"TP033500","student_name":"Ryan Teh Hoon Meng","student_username":"teh","student_password":"123"}]

this is the results i got from the "content" variable that was passed into the parseFeed(String content)

Comment: Your java code is not getting that response. Try changing this: `System.out.println("begin parsing");` to `System.out.println("begin parsing: " + content);` and post that output.

Comment: @pherris,     begin parsing: [{"student_id":"TP028616","student_name":"Shirlyn Hoe Yee Lyn","student_username":"lyn","student_password":"123"},{"student_id":"TP033500","student_name":"Ryan Teh Hoon Meng","student_username":"teh","student_password":"123"}]

Comment: @pherris, it was really the problem with the php file. i tried creating another php file and i works like a charm.

Comment: It seems that somehow you had some extra characters between `"student_id": "TP033500"` and the trailing comma `,`. If you copy/paste the code you had in your comments. I'd guess that was the issue, but I cannot see why from your PHP file unless it's the trailing spaces? Sounds like you got it fixed though!